# Unable to attach a Layer to Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function (Node.js 8.10) in `us-west-2` and I am unable to attach the layer `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:553035198032:layer:git:3`. I get the following error message upon save:
`You are not authorized to perform: lambda:GetLayerVersion.`

I have the `AWSLambdaFullAccess` managed policy attached to my user, and even the persons with `AdministratorAccess` get the same error. I also checked in the policy simulator and it specifies that this permission IS allowed to be run by myself and the Administrator users.

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

REGION MISMATCH

I followed the README [here](https://github.com/lambci/git-lambda-layer), but failed to notice the region difference, nor the **Version ARNs** section that implies the package author has created the layer in multiple regions.